COM interface and returning the structs
I keep thinking about how best to implement the interaction between a shared (DLL) library and an application in C++. I settled on the idea of ​​a COM interface. The essence of this idea is that we have purely virtual classes (interfaces) in header files:
class INode
{
public:
    virtual ~INode() = default;
    virtual ENodeType type() = 0;
    virtual void set_name(const char* name_str) noexcept = 0;
    [[nodiscard]] virtual const char* name() noexcept = 0;
    [[nodiscard]] virtual INode* parent() noexcept = 0;
    [[nodiscard]] virtual INode* children() noexcept = 0;
    [[nodiscard]] virtual unsigned children_count() noexcept = 0;
    virtual EResultCode add_child(INode* node) noexcept = 0;
    virtual EResultCode remove_child(INode* node) noexcept = 0;
};

But they are not exported from the library directly, only some functions are exported (in pure C style), which create real objects inside the library and simply return a pointer (of interface type) to this created object:
extern "C"
{
    LIB_API INode* create_node();
    LIB_API void destroy_node(const INode* node);
}

As a result, the user (of lib) only deals with pointers to objects. This way we don’t need to export classes and at the same time OOP seems to work.
But my goal is to ensure that only information about what architecture the library was compiled on (x86 or x64) would be enough for its reliable use, regardless of the compiler (let’s say the library was compiled by one compiler for x86, but it can be used in application compiled by another compiler for x86)
But several questions arise.

Is there any guarantee in C++ that standard types (int, float, char*, etc.) will always (in all compilers) be the same size for the same architecture? Is there some way to guarantee this?
In the case of a COM interface, is it a good idea to return (and pass as an argument to methods) structures? Let's say I have a structure declared somewhere in the headers (consisting of fields of these standard types), and on the library side the method returns it. Even if I achieve a guarantee that all the fields of the structure will be the same types in any compilers, are there any pitfalls here (like “in compiler A, these structures are packed in one order, and in compiler B - in another + some alignment). I can, of course, return references or pointers to these structures, but this does not change the essence (it is still important how exactly the bytes are located in the structure).

I tried returning structures, and even types from the standard library (such as std::vector), it worked (on same compiler & cpp standard), but the question is - will it always work? I would like to understand what is worth doing and what is not, and what options there are.

"I settled on the idea of ​​a COM interface" - the code you showed is not using COM. COM is an actual well-defined technology that several C/C++ compilers and other programming languages support. Your code is taking inspiration from COM, but is not using actual COM.

surprisingly the answer of both questions is NO, there are no guarantees that would work, but on most operating system the compilers will try to match the important types to be able to call system C libraries, but no guarantees provided, for example even on x86_64 the compilers disagree how an int128 should behave.

And also note that, at least on windows, you cannot mix x86 and x86-64 in the same process. A 64-bit process cannot directly load a 32-bit DLL. There are ways to have a helped process of the correct bitedness and then USE inter-process communication. But such a but in that case the original process must be aware of the fact that it is not using in-process loading.

@AhmedAEK "but on most operating system the compilers will try to match the important types" - But what about structures? Will the compiler try to behave similarly with structures consisting of these types, or, for example, the structure allocated in MinGW (C++ 11) will differ from the same one in MSVC (C++17)?

@AlexNem both the padding and the virtual function dispatch mechanism are not part of the C or C++ standard, and are left to the implementers (compilers) to decide how to implement them, i am sure MinGW maintainers do their best to be compatible with MSVC, but MSVC can do breaking changes, so can MinGW maintainers, there is no document that says they have to act the same, IMO just have a test suite to check when the ABI is broken by one of the compilers, you just have to pass objects across library boundaries and check their value.

Passing non-POD data across library/module boundaries is always risky.  Even when using the same compiler on both sides, different compiler settings can affect the result.  So, just don't do it at all.

@RemyLebeau, ok, that means passing a POD data (for example struct of POD-type fields) across lib boundary - it's ok?

Also, as far as I know, it is possible to explicitly set the way data is packed in a structure using #pragma pack. Could this somehow help ensure structures are same on the library and application side?
